# Injecting @value Resource (json file) while testing method in Junit5

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, junit5

**Service class :**

```java
    @Value("classpath:multipleHearingLocations.json")
        public static Resource resource;
    
    
    public void someMethod(){
    
       ConcurrentHashMap<String,List<String>> multipleHearingLocations = new Objec`enter code here`tMapper().readValue(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(**resource.getURI()**)), new TypeReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>>(){});
    
    }
    
    someTest.json - resided in my main/resources folder
    
    While testing in Jusint5, test class
    
    @Value("classpath:multipleHearingLocations.json")
        public static Resource resource;
```

But when I test it - the service calss throws a null pointer exception saying resource is null.

**Test Method :**

```java
   @Mock
       public static Resource resource;
       enter code here
   
    @Test
       void getMultipleHearingLocations_shouldReturnCorrespondingMultipleEpimsIdForVenue() throws IOException {
           SscsCaseData caseData = SscsCaseData.builder()
               .appeal(Appeal.builder()
                           .hearingOptions(HearingOptions.builder().build())
                           .build())
               .processingVenue(PROCESSING_VENUE_1)
               .build();
   
   //        = new ClassPathResource("multipleHearingLocationsTest.json");
           given(venueService.getEpimsIdForVenue(caseData.getProcessingVenue())).willReturn(Optional.of("443014"));
           given(referenceDataServiceHolder.getVenueService()).willReturn(venueService);
           given(**resource.getURI()**).willReturn(new ClassPathResource("multipleHearingLocationsTest.json").getURI());
           List<HearingLocation> result = HearingsDetailsMapping.getHearingLocations(
               caseData,
               referenceDataServiceHolder
           );
```

**What is it that I am doing wrong?**
Or is there a way to inject the Resource in the tests as well, so that it is available as a bean when the service class is called?
Tried running it as below, still no luck

```java
    RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = HearingsDetailsMapping.class)
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:multipleHearingLocationsTest.json")
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried not mocking the Resource?

Comment: Hi Kris, Mock dosen't work. The resource is null when I test it.

Comment: yeah that is why I asked if you have tried not mocking it and letting it run

Comment: Ohh, I misread the question.. Not mocking doesn't work. @values is not able to initialize the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter the same problem. This injection method works fine with JUnit 4 but not with Junit5.

@RunsWith is a JUnit 4 annotation the JUnit 5 equivalent is @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61435598/18876695) for more details.

To inject a resource in JUnit 5 you could use [this working soulution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64946688/18876695)

or

```
File getFile(String fileLocation) {
    return new File(this
        .getClass()
        .getClassLoader()
        .getResource(fileLocation)
        .getFile());
  }

String filelocation = "multipleHearingLocations.json" //(no "class:" before path)
```

**Path** to multipleHearingLocations.json while testing: **src/test/resources/multipleHearingLocations.json**