# How to access a file from resources folder in test in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, bazel, spring-boot-test, bazel-java

My file "products.yml" is located in src/test/resources/configs folder. I have defined config import in my application.yml in springboot

```
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - optional:configtree:src/test/resources/configs/
```

I am trying to get this "products.yml" filepath using @Value annotation in my configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class ProductConverterConfiguration {

@Value("${products}") 
private String productsYamlFile;

System.out.Println("Got the file as: " + productsYamlFile);
}
```

Springboot is unable to see that file when I try to run bazel test for that class it fails with null pointer exception.

I tried giving absolute path in the application.yaml and it works.
But I need the relative path since I wont have the same host when I deploy this application. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot: How to read resource from classpath in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428305/spring-boot-how-to-read-resource-from-classpath-in-unit-test)

Comment: When you deploy the application, you won't have a `src` folder either. So `src/test/resources/configs` is definitely wrong there.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code ?

application.yml

```
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - optional:configtree:classpath:configs/
```

ProductConverterConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
public class ProductConverterConfiguration {

    @Value("${products}") 
    private String productsYamlFile;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Got the file as: " + productsYamlFile);
    }
}
```

(can you chare product.yml if it doesn't work)